# Movie length not displaying the first 0 EX: 30:1 instead of 30:01

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml, content-management-system

I have a website that I use a CMS to upload videos. They are all placed on my site with their appropriate movie lengths. I recently noticed however if a movie length ended in a :0 then the 0 will not be displayed so anything that ends in two 0's will look like   10:     and anything  that starts with a 0 will only display the second number.

I did some investigation and found that the file being pulled is this is called movie_length.tpl   and tried to decipher the code.... I also noticed there is a file called movie_length_custom that Im sharing the code with aswell just in case it may be in that one.

If anyone could help me out in this would be great!

THIS FIRST CODE IS THE ONE WHERE I THINK THE PROBLEM LIES

```
{**
Display MoviewLenght file
@param lenght 
**}
{if $length}
{math equation="floor(el)" el=$length assign="flen"} 

 {if ($flen<60) }0:{$flen}&nbsp;
 {else}
    {math equation="floor(el/60)" el=$flen assign="fl"}
    {$fl}:{if ($flen % 60)!= 0}{math equation="floor(el % 60)" el=$flen assign="s"}{$s}    {/if}
{/if}
{/if}

In case its not there here is the other possible code


{if isset($data.PreviewXML.content.names.name_attr[0].movie_length)}
{include file="$spath/general/display_movielength.tpl" length=$data.PreviewXML.content.names.name_attr[0].movie_length}
{else}
{foreach from=$item.PreviewXML.content.names.name_attr item="length"}
    {if ($length.name == "sourcemp4")}
        {include file="$spath/general/display_movielength.tpl"  length=$length.movie_length}
    {/if}
{/foreach}
```

{/if}